# Fourier Transform of Jacobi Elliptic Functions

Tags: calculus, fourier-transform

Long story short, I was bored and wanted to find the Fourier Transform of the three basic Jacobi Elliptic Functions $\mathbf{sn}(x\mid k)$, $\mathbf{cn}(x\mid k)$, and $\mathbf{dn}(x\mid k)$. However, when I went searching for an answer on the internet, no one really seemed to have one. Therefore, I attempted to solve it by hand.

Because the proof is a bit long, I will place in a few basics:

(1) I used the [Fourier Series Representations](http://dlmf.nist.gov/22.11) of these functions

(2) I changed the functions from $\mathbf{pn}(x\mid k)$ to $\mathbf{pn}(2\pi t \mid k)$ ($\mathbf{p}$ can be $\mathbf{s,c,d}$) so that it could be much simpler to do the transform.

(3) I evaluated $\mathbf{sn}$ to be:

$$\mathcal{F\{\mathbf{sn}(2\pi t\mid k)\}(s)}=\frac{\pi}{ikK} \sum^\infty_{n=0}\frac{q^{n+\frac{1}{2}}(\delta(s-\frac{\pi(2n+1)}{2K})-\delta(s + \frac{\pi(2n+1)}{2K}))}{1-q^{2n+1}}$$

where $K\equiv K(k)=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{d\theta}{\sqrt{1-k^2\sin^2\theta}}$, $k$ is the elliptic modulus (eccentricity), $k'$ is the complimentary modulus ($k'=\sqrt{1-k^2}$), $q=e^{\frac{-\pi K(k')}{K(k)}}$ (the nome)

I wish to know if this is the right solution to the problem. Also, here is a thing that [I made in Desmos for the Elliptic Functions](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/kuymi4vh3k).
I will hope to add more to this, but I may have to type it up on a word doc to have it explained thoroughly.

Comment: the Fourier series are there https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi_elliptic_functions#Expansion_in_terms_of_the_nome

Comment: Yes, if $f(x) = \sum_n c_n e^{2 i \pi n x}$ then $\hat{f}(\xi ) = \sum_n c_n \delta(\xi-n)$ where $\delta$ is the Dirac delta distribution